# How to properly install windows in hyper-v to use the included virtualization rights?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, licensing

I have a server I am redoing for a client. I want to take advantage of hyper-v and run VMs for them. The issue is I only have one physical key for the server. However I have read that the copy of windows I have (Windows Server 2012 R2) grants me 2 virtual licenses to use with hyper-v.

The issue is I don't know how to use them. Do I just use the same key again for each hyper-v instance?

Any insight into this matter?

Comment: To my knowledge this key is not a MAK key. It is not part of a volume license.

Answer (score 1):

Server licensing is all about the physical hardware of the server and purely for auditing purposes. The product key you receive will be used to MAK activate the physical Windows Server 2012 standard server and also for activating up to two Server 2012 standard VMs on the physical server (hyper-v host).

Here is an excellent reference for Windows Server 2012 licensing. http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2012/10/29/windows-server-and-processor-cores-part-2-windows-server-2012.aspx

Just to note: You activate the Windows server VM the same way as physical Windows computers. With your license you're given a product key. If OEM use the product key given to you from Dell, HP, etc. if it is a volume license, you can get the product key at the Microsoft volume licensing center.